# Decode - From bytes to any

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

This is Python 2

My understanding is,

*decode* is about decoding **from** bytes **to** anything(ascii/codepoint/utf-8/whatever..)

*encode* is about encoding **from** unicode code points to anything(bytes/ascii/utf-8/...)

From the below code,

```
>>> myUtf8
'Hi \xe2\x84\x99\xc6\xb4\xe2\x98\x82\xe2\x84\x8c\xc3\xb8\xe1\xbc\xa4'
>>> myUtf8.decode("ascii", "replace")
u'Hi \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd'
>>> myUtf8.decode('utf-16')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 18: truncated data
```

**Question**:

Why code point `\ufffd` is replaced for the bytes that can't be decoded?

Edit:

**Question:**

Agreement (say) is bytes are being received. how to find, bytes are expressed in which encoding? Assuming those bytes are being received from network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong. `decode` is "from bytes expressed in the encoding you pass as first parameter to `unicode`"; `encode` is "from `unicode` to bytes expressed in the encoding you pass as first parameter".

In your example, you give some bytes expressed in UTF-8 and tell to Python to interpret them as ASCII to then build a `unicode` string; given that all the >127 bytes aren't valid ASCII, they are considered garbage, and thus, as you requested with the `"replace"` parameter, they are replaced with the Unicode replacement character.

Comment: when you say, from bytes expressed in the given encoding, I think, you mean,  bytes expressed in ascii/cp1252/latin-1/utf-8(7 bit plane same as ascii)

Comment: There's no way to know *a priori*. You must read the documentation of the remote program, or at least study its output to determine the encoding of the data it produces; UTF-8 is very easy to spot, other encodings less so. There are many tools you can use to guess the encoding (for example, the `chardet` module), although you shouldn't use them at runtime unless you are completely desperate, since they only produce statistical guesses, which may be incorrect.

Comment: It's also important to ask yourself if your program actually needs to decode that data - if it can just treat it as an opaque blob of bytes you can avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: Ouch you changed the comment... I mean what I wrote, bytes expressed in the encoding you pass as first argument of `decode` (which yes, can be for example one of those you wrote).

Comment: Is your definition of decode/ encode considered valid across python versions?

Comment: @overexchange: yes, and in Python 3 they are even a little more logical. In Python 2 you have `encode` and `decode` both on `str` and `unicode` objects, which is quite stupid because it doesn't make much sense to try to encode in some encoding a string of unknown encoding (which is cause of endless confusion when you do `s.encode(...)` and Python gives you a `UnicodeDecodeError`, because *first* it tries to convert the `str` to `unicode` using the `ascii` codec, *then* calls `encode` - and frequently fails on the first step).

Comment: Python 3 instead have `encode` only on `str` objects (which are Python 2's `unicode` objects), and `decode` only on `byte` objects (which are similar to Python 2's `str` objects).

Comment: So, **1)** if you say, *from bytes* in your answer, then, I can generalize to *from `str` type object* in python2 and *from `bytes` type object* in python3. **2)** if you say, *from `unicode`* in your answer, then, I can generalize to *from `unicode` type object* in python2 and *from `str` type object* in python3.